# Oracle table exist query searching tables in all database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 20 oracle database in my machine when i am trying to run below script it searching the table in all the database how to tell query to search on particular or single database .

```
if not exists (select * from dba_tables where table_name='Default')
    create table Default (
          FolderType [VARCHAR](4) NOT NULL,
          FeeCode [INT] NOT NULL,
          StatusCode [INT] NOT NULL,
          CalculationOrder [INT] NULL,
          FeeAmount] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
          BillFlag] [CHAR](1) NULL,
          Comments] [VARCHAR](4000) NULL,

    )
go

ALTER TABLE Default  ADD CONSTRAINT Default_PK PRIMARY KEY (FolderType, FeeCode, StatusCode)
GO
```

Comment: I Think by "database" here you mean schema/user.

Comment: Yes right plenty of schema

Comment: well first those are sybase syntax not oracle . are you sure you are using oracle ? because it differ from ora and syb

Comment: Yes i am using Oracle Database

Comment: The create table statement is invalid SQL. You can't possibly run that on an Oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `user_tables` instead of `dba_tables` will give you the tables only in the user/schema you are logged in.